# Custom Backend Timezone for Store Views or Users

Tags: backend, localisation

We have a multi-store setup with different countries.
It looks like in the backend always the timezone is used which is configured for the Default Config scope at System -> Config -> General -> General -> Locale Options.

Is there a way to use the timezone of the specific country?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to the bottom of the admin panel you will see a locale drop down. Change to the appropriate locale. See image.

[image: locale dropdown]